# how to write apex code for my trigger?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, custom-object

This is my trigger for invoice object how to write apex class for this.

```
trigger Insertnewinvoice on Invoice__c (after insert) {
    // minimize DML statments
    List<Invoicelineitem__c> InvoicelineitemList = new List<Invoicelineitem__c>();
    Set<Id> quoteIdSet = new Set<Id>();

    for (Invoice__c to : trigger.new) {
        quoteIdSet.add(to.Quote__c);
    }

    list<QuoteLineItem> ql = [SELECT id,
                                     ListPrice,
                                     PriceBookEntry.Product2Id,
                                     Subtotal,
                                     TotalPrice 
                              FROM QuoteLineItem 
                              WHERE QuoteId IN :quoteIdSet];

    for(QuoteLineItem qli : ql){
        Invoicelineitem__c lm = new Invoicelineitem__c();
        lm.List_Price__c = qli.ListPrice;
        lm.Product__c = qli.PriceBookEntry.Product2Id;
        lm.Order__c = to.id;
        InvoicelineitemList.add(lm);
    }

    insert InvoicelineitemList;
}
```

Could any one please help me out from this issue.

Comment: What do you want to do with apex class?

Comment: i want to  Create Invoice line Items...

Comment: You are creating invoicelineitems from within trigger itself. Do you want to move this code to apex class?

Comment: i am new to SFDC How to activate the trigger.. for that i need to write any Apex class...???

Comment: For activating a trigger you dont need apex class. You can see a checkbox on top of the trigger. Enable the check box to activate.

Comment: The trigger is "activated" whenever you insert an invoice. The above code will then execute.  do a google search for apex triggers to read all about them